# List NPM packages with post-install hooks

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

For running my build on a CI/CD that's inside an isolated network I would like to know what the postinstall scripts in my project are doing, so I can configure the network accordingly.

Is there a better way than reverse engineering to see which packages execute postinstall scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the original question, you can run some command like this to get a list of all deps that have postinstall scripts:

```bash
npm query ":attr(scripts, [postinstall])" | jq 'map(.name)'
```

Answer (score 0):

there is [@lavamoat/allow-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lavamoat/allow-scripts).

simply add

```
"lavamoat": {
  "allowScripts": {
      "@some/script-with-postinstall": true
  }
}
```

to the `package.json` to run the postinstall of the allowed scripts.

```
npx allow-scripts auto
```

can be used to detect scripts with a postinstall hook